# htaccess URL Rewrite trying to simplify current one

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have an htaccess file already that works fine, but I want to change it from having a bunch of parameters to only one.

so my current htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(_modules|css|files|fonts|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|) index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5&p6=$6&p7=$7&p8=$8 [L,QSA]
```

so I modified it to look like this:
Options +FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(_modules|css|files|fonts|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*|)/? index.php?p1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but all of the sudden none of my css, or external files work anymore.

Does anyone have any suggestions how how to get a htaccess url to work so that it can change a url from

`http://www.example.com/template/index.php?controller=blog/i-am-a-title`

to

`http://www.example.com/template/blog/i-am-a-title`

and still have it so `css/style.css` works

Comment: If you have that complicated .htaccess files, just forward everything to PHP and check $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. And create something like www.example.com/assets/ which you exclude from redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|(_modules|css|files|fonts|ico|img|js)/)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Not very good: http://www.example.com/helicopter.html would trigger ico and js is even worse

Comment: @Aragon0: Didn't understand your comment, can you explain a bit.

Comment: Your condition for exclusion triggers too often. If you have an url like /json.html your exclusion rule matches /js it and doesn't forward it to index.php

Comment: When ever I try to use this I get `The requested URL template/blog/i-am-a-title/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? Is it placed in `blog` directory?

Comment: there is no blog directory, that is part of the url. as for the example given.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your page's header:

```
<base href="/template/">
```

If your styles are all relative links, then when the URL changes to `/template/blog/i-am-a-title`, the relative URL base changes to `/template/blog/` and your relative links will all break.

Comment: Do you know any php that I could use to determine the base than. Because I was using this and found that when I moved from my testting server to my actually servers I had to go and change all of the files.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Try something like `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`